# What is the error in my XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my xml file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">
    <body>
        <shelf>
            <cd id="el01">
                <artist>Elton John</artist>
                <title>Circle of Life</title>
                <country>UK</country>
                <company>Spectrum</company>
                <price>10.90</price>
                <year>1999</year>
                <description>As heard in the Lion King.</description>
            </cd>

            <book id="bk101">
                <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
                <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
                <genre>Computer</genre>
                <price>44.95</price>
                <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
                <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.
                </description>
            </book>

          </shelf>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my XSL file

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
     syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
-->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>The Shelf</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>The Shelf</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="shelf"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//shelf">
    <xsl:for-each select="cd|book">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

My output is just "The Shelf" in the browser. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. Your data has a namespace "http://www.w3schools.com", however you can't just declare this in your xslt and use it - due to a mismatch in the xml/xpath specs you need to change your selectors as well. I've declared a 'data' prefix to match your xml documents default name space, then changed all your xpath selects to match. Unfortunatly you can't just a default namespace, as default name spaces don't work in xpath. (alternatively, you could have removed the default namespace from your xml document, but this might not always be an option).
2. Your shelf selector won't find any matching nodes relative to '/'. I've change your initial apply templates to //data:shelf to match all data:shelf nodes that can be found anywhere in your document.

try the following

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:data="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<!-- TODO customize transformation rules
 syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt
-->
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Shelf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The Shelf</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//data:shelf"/>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//data:shelf">
<xsl:for-each select="data:cd|data:book">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="data:title"/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the namespace issue!. Note though that generally using the `//` shortcut isn't great as it looks for all matching nodes at all levels - which may be inefficient in large docs. its better to go for the actual path if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

Your select="shelf" is wrong. Should work if you just remove it. Or try select="html/body/shelf".

Answer (score 0):

Your line `<xsl:apply-templates select="shelf"/>` will be applied in the context of the root node (ie html/shelf). There are no shelf nodes at this level.

Chaning that line to `<xsl:apply-templates select="body/shelf"/>` should be sufficient.